# Converting strings to lowercase

Tags: string, case-sensitive, rust

How does one convert a string to a lowercase or perform some kind of equivalency comparison ignoring case? There is an ignore case on the `Ascii` type but it seems convoluted and I don't see a way to convert `str` to `Ascii`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`std::ascii::AsciiExt.eq_ignore_ascii_case`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html#tymethod.eq_ignore_ascii_case) does what you want:

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;

fn main() {
    assert!("foo".eq_ignore_ascii_case("FOO"));
}
```

(The search in the docs is quite good now; searches like "case" and "ascii" return good sets of results which contain this solution.)

Comment: I did search for those, but didn't notice it had implementors on `str`. Also if I'm not mistaken, `~"foo".as_slice().eq_ignore_ascii_case(owned_str.as_slice())` should work on owned strings, right?

Comment: Owned strings can be automatically sliced, so that `(~"foo").eq_ignore_ascii_case(~"FOO")` works just fine without the need to call the `as_slice()` method on it. (Try it and see!)

Comment: renamed to: [`std::ascii::AsciiExt.eq_ignore_ascii_case`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html#tymethod.eq_ignore_ascii_case) in 1.0

Answer (score 4):

From that [same trait](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ascii/trait.AsciiExt.html#tymethod.to_ascii_lower), `std::ascii::StrAsciiExt.to_ascii_upper` and `std::ascii::StrAsciiExt.to_ascii_lower` are also very handy.

Comment: Looks like they are now `to_ascii_lowercase` and `to_ascii_uppercase` as of 1.0.0